# Comparative power requirements of various wireless networking protocols

Tags: protocols, power-consumption

Does anyone have a ***real- world*** comparison of various wireless networking protocols, such as Zigbee, LoRa, BTLE (and BT5, if there any production models to measure), even WiFi (any others)?

I am interested in a real-world comparison, rather than just marketing hype.

I am interested firstly in power consumption on battery and then on achievable broadcast range (plus trade-off ratio).

For my interests (and most IoT projects, I imagine), I am not interested in continuous transmission. I will probably be sending small < 128 byte packets once per minute or every few minutes, possibly hourly. That might play some role if hardware dedicated to a particular protocol has a good sleep mode when not Tx/Rx.

Comment: That's one data packet of said size once per minute, e.g. pure payload of (unsecured?) raw data or are you tied to a higher level protocol with whatever handshakes that brings, correct? I'm asking because that's an amount of bytes in header level size categories, (e.g. unsecured http get header is about twenty something bytes. A TLS handshake about 1k if I remember correctly. So the payload would potentially be dwarfed by protocol encapsulation, meta data and headers. (1/2)

Comment: It might be prudent to list the whole stack of protocols you want to employ. Otherwise your protocol stack might kill the assumptions you are using to pick the wireless protocol. Unfortunately that makes it also less likely that you'll find that matching real-world comparison. (2/2)

Comment: Great points! I think I will leave it as-is, in hope of any answer, even if it is slightly more ballpark than accurate to my single use case.

Comment: Can you give a rough X consumes more than Y consumes more than Z?

Comment: Unfortunately no, at least not in what I'd say qualifies as real-world comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

This is ***NOT*** an answer.

It is just a sketchpad area for the OP dump some stuff that needs further research & will soon be deleted.

- [Choosing the Right Wireless Protocol for Your IoT Application](https://www.electronicdesign.com/industrial-automation/choosing-right-wireless-protocol-your-iot-application)
  A good, non-technical, overview of various popular protocols.

  > The low-power solution offered by LoRaWAN is well-suited for battery-powered IoT devices and can support battery life of 10 years and more
  >   Marketing hype, no doubt, but still indicative.
- [Bluetooth or WiFi – Which is Best for Your New Wireless Product?](https://predictabledesigns.com/what-type-of-wireless-is-right-for-your-product-bluetooth-wifi/)

  > A BLE device can run for a year or two on a single watch battery. This is possible primarily because these types of products are designed to only transmit occasionally. For example, a BLE device may only transmit data for 1 second once per minute. This means the device is idle for 59/60 = 98.3% of the time.
- [Review of Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) Solutions](https://predictabledesigns.com/review-of-bluetooth-low-energy-ble-solutions/)

Comment: For what it's worth, the changes for BT5 were intended to improve range by 4 and reduce power (by 2?). But the last time I went looking for BT5 hardware (a few weeks ago) there was only one chipset/module barely arrived on the market.

Comment: I could be wrong, but i think that the protocol offers a trade off; i.e  doubling the range halves the data rat, and vice versa. The new Raspberry Pi 4 [has BT 5](https://www.slashgear.com/5-ways-the-raspberry-pi-4-is-a-huge-upgrade-24581476/), as does the Orange Pi 3 ([here](are specs for 125 Linux boards). It might be worth checking AliExpress

Comment: For BT5, see also , the new Sparkfun Artemis ... https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/designing-with-the-sparkfun-artemis

Comment: And the STM32WB series - https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32wb-series.html